# How do I query MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I just created a collection and am trying to query certain objects inside the document but I seem to get no results. Btw I am using Robomongo for the GUI for mongoDB.These are my documents.

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58f58ba6739e558ced008df1"),
"Inventory for NTA SAM Cards" : "Item no.",
"Item Description" : "",
"Opening QTY" : "",
"Issued QTY" : "",
"Corrupted QTY" : "",
"Closing QTY" : ""
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58f58f23739e558ced008e3d"),
"Inventory for NTA SAM Cards" : "01",
"Item Description" : "EZ-Link SAM (Blank)",
"Opening QTY" : "165",
"Issued QTY" : "65",
"Corrupted QTY" : "0",
"Closing QTY" : "100",
"Remarks" : "Received 100 blank SAMS from Geraldine on 4/1/15"
 }

/* 3 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58f58f9c739e558ced008e47"),
"Inventory for NTA SAM Cards" : "02",
"Item Description" : "EZ-Link SAM (Test)",
"Opening QTY" : "220",
"Issued QTY" : "184",
"Corrupted QTY" : "0",
"Closing QTY" : "36",
"Remarks" : "updated 7/11/16"
 }

 /* 4 */
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("58f58fcd739e558ced008e4d"),
"Inventory for NTA SAM Cards" : "03",
"Item Description" : "EZL Production SAM",
"Opening QTY" : "998",
"Issued QTY" : "996",
"Corrupted QTY" : "0",
"Closing QTY" : "2",
"Remarks" : "updated 11/11/2016 150 moved to 18.Auresys Prod"
 }

 /* 5 */
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("58f59034739e558ced008e57"),
"Inventory for NTA SAM Cards" : "04",
"Item Description" : "Payment Link SAM",
"Opening QTY" : "500",
"Issued QTY" : "500",
"Corrupted QTY" : "0",
"Closing QTY" : "0",
"Remarks" : ""
 }

 /* 6 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58f5a1b2739e558ced008f2e"),
"Inventory for NTA SAM Cards" : "05",
"Item Description" : "MEA Production SAM",
"Opening QTY" : "434",
"Issued QTY" : "393",
"Corrupted QTY" : "0",
"Closing QTY" : "41",
"Remarks" : ""
}
```

Does anyone know whats the problem? My query is

```
 db.documents.find({"Inventory for NTA SAM Cards":"01"})
```

I kept getting this

```
Fetched 0 record(s) in 2ms
```

My collection is called documents.

Comment: what is your collection name? is it `documents`? and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: yes my collection name is documents i keep getting this   Fetched 0 record(s) in 2ms.

Comment: Your query looks correct to me; the syntax is good, your field name is correct, your field value is correct, and everything is quoted correctly. Maybe the collection name is wrong, or you are connected to the wrong database? It's worth trying out other queries such as `db.documents.find({"_id" : ObjectId("58f58f23739e558ced008e3d")})` to see if they also fail to return any records.

Comment: @VinceBowdren It required me to `{$eq:"01"}` in order to get the query out by following the link in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
db.documents.find( { Inventory for NTA SAM Cards: { $eq: "01" } } )
```

for reference fallow this link

[db.collection.find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)

Comment: It worked out once I used yours with two quotation marks.   
                                                                      
               db.documents.find({"Inventory for NTA SAM Cards":{$eq:"01"}})

Comment: Usually when would i require the quotation marks for queries?

Comment: it depends on the syntax of methods . for find method you don't have to use quotation marks for field names and you don't have to use quotation marks if the value in the field is numeric . if it is text you have to use quotation marks

Comment: Does that include field names with text ? Do I have to use quotation marks for the numeric value like the one with `{$eq:"01"}` ?

Comment: you have stored numeric value as string that is why you have to use quotation mark